# SQLY query error with Aggregates and renaming: unexpected token "age, SUM(BALANCE) AS TOTALBALANCE, DISTINCT COUNT(id" was found following "SELECT "

Tags: sql, db2

```
SELECT age, SUM(BALANCE) AS TOTALBALANCE, DISTINCT COUNT(id) AS ids 
FROM p1.account 
  JOIN p1.customer ON p1.customer.id=p1.account.id 
HAVING (age>=%s AND age<=%s)
```

I'm getting this error:

> An unexpected token "age, SUM(BALANCE) AS TOTALBALANCE, DISTINCT
> COUNT(id" was found following "SELECT ".  Expected tokens may include:
> "".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.26.14

Any reason why my query isn't working. Not quite sure what I'm doing wrong with my query string

Comment: Your query makes no sense.  Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the results.  What is `distinct` supposed to be doing, for instance?  Also tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff i'm trying to find the average total balance of users within a certain age range (users may have multiple bank accounts, thus I need to get the number of unique User Ids (id) ). I have two tables, p1.account and p1.customer (account contains balance and id, customer contains age, hence the need for a join.

Comment: Make it easy, and possible, to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: `distinct` can only com right after `select` and it always applies to all column (or expressions) in the SELECT list.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't working because you missed the `GROUP BY` clause

Try

```sql
SELECT age, SUM(BALANCE) AS TOTALBALANCE, COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS ids 
FROM p1.account JOIN p1.customer ON p1.customer.id=p1.account.id 
GROUP BY age 
HAVING (age>=%s AND age<=%s)
```

Comment: that didn't work. Still getting this error. Seems to be with my select statement

An unexpected token "age, SUM(BALANCE) AS TOTALBALANCE, DISTINCT COUNT(id" was found following "SELECT ".  Expected tokens may include:  "<PiStart>".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.26.14

Comment: try adding p1.customer.age if age comes from p1.customer.

Comment: great, i fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment (which should really be in the question):

> i'm trying to find the average total balance of users within a certain age range (users may have multiple bank accounts, thus I need to get the number of unique User Ids (id) ).

This suggests two levels of aggregation.  The first is to get the total balance for each customer.  I think this is the logic:

```
select c.id, sum(balance) as customer_balance
from  p1.account a join
      p1.customer c
      on c.id = a.id
where age >= %s and age <= %s
group by c.id;
```

The second is to get the average balance:

```
select avg(customer_balance)
from (select c.id, sum(balance) as customer_balance
      from  p1.account a join
            p1.customer c
            on c.id = a.id
      where age >= %s and age <= %s
      group by c.id
     ) c;
```

You don't really need two levels of aggregation, but that is the simplest way to explain the logic.  This should do the same thing:

```
select sum(a.balance) / count(distinct c.id) as customer_balance
from  p1.account a join
      p1.customer c
      on c.id = a.id
where age >= %s and age <= %s;
```

Note that in either case, you can `group by age` if that is what you really want.  Your question, though, suggests that you want all the ages combined.